# how to give a array input for if statement in c?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, input, scanf

```
# include <stdio.h>


void danidev(void){
 printf("Dani is a YouTuber and an indie game developer and an fps game developer having his game published in play store he is 22 years old and goes to a university");
}

void brackeys(void){
    printf("brackeys is a YouTuber and an indie game developer and also an fps game developer having most of his games published in itch.io and has a team which works on game development");
}

void blackthornprod(void){
    printf("  they are two brothers who create video games and teach others how to do the same over on Youtube and Udemy ! they are passionate in sharing their knowledge and game creation journey with other aspiring game developers.");
}

void jabrils(void){
 printf("jabrils is a ai programmer and also a machine learning pro coder and also a game developer he has made a lot of ai and has saved millions of people from their tough times");
}

void codingbullet(void){
 printf("coding bullet is a multi intelligent ai developer and also a master in machine learning also he owns a youtube channel with 2.06 million subscribers");
}

int main(){

 printf("HERE IS THE INFORMATION OF FAMOUS CODING YOUTUBERS(PLS TYPE THE FOLLWOING YOUTUBERS NAME): ");
 char b;
 scanf("%c",&b);
 if(b=='danidev'){
 danidev(); 
 }
 else if(b=='brackeys'){
 brackeys();
 }
 else if(b=='blackthornprod'){
 blackthornprod();
 }
 else if(b=='jabrils'){
 jabrils();
 }
 else if(b=='codingbullet'){
 codingbullet();
 }
 else{
 printf(" i dont know what you are taking about");
 }

return 0;
}
```

I have a problem when I enter a YouTubers name ( complete name) as an input  I get a problem that the constant is too long and does not give the proper result and also it says the constant character is too long for its type

Comment: use double quotes `""` to create string literals, not single-quotes.  Create a `char` array to store the results of your `scanf`, and use `%s` to read a string rather than `%c` to read a single character.

Comment: thanks, Christian Gibbons for your help

Comment: I suggest that you work your way through a beginning C programming course. There are many free ones online.

Comment: Hi bob Jarvis, I newly started learning c and I am a 12-year-old kid(how is smart) I learn c by myself in educative.io @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate more space for the input.
The type `char` is only going to hold one character. You need an array of `char`s. This can be declared as follows:

```
char b[30];
```

This will hold 30 characters.

For string literals, you should use double quotes not single quotes. e.g. `"danidev"` as opposed to `'danidev'`.

When comparing strings (arrays of characters) you should use the `strcmp()` function.

Please read the documentation for it: [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Since you are starting out, I would also recommend looking at some tutorials for strings in C. [String Functions](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-strings-string-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly compare strings using the equality operator (==). Instead, use strcmp() to compare two strings.

```
char str[20];
gets(str);

if(!strcmp(str, "danidev") danidev();  //Use double quotes for strings, instead of single quotes (used for character literal).
//Same as strcmp(str, "danidev") == 0
//rest of the code
```

Also, if you're a beginner, I suggest you to check some C's String library functions.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of errors, from string comparison, string definition and char/char array variables. It looks like JS sometimes, but take care of the big differences.
Beside that, I have seen another answer has been added while I was writing this one, I want to add to pay attention at the length of array in scanf so you don't raise a buffer overflow error at runtime.

You can check it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/HyrgvK-sL

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void danidev (void)
{
  printf ("Dani is a YouTuber and an indie game developer and an fps game developer having his game published in play store he is 22 years old and goes to a university");
}

int main ()
{

    printf("HERE IS THE INFORMATION OF FAMOUS CODING YOUTUBERS(PLS TYPE THE FOLLWOING YOUTUBERS NAME): ");
    char b[32];
    scanf("%31s", b);

    if (strncmp(b,"danidev", 32)== 0) 
    {
        danidev ();
    }
    else
    {
        printf (" i dont know what you are taking about");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi could you please explain about `if (strncmp(b,"danidev", 32)== 0)` what it does and how please

Comment: Sure, strncmp does a string compare. In C a string is an array of characters terminated by a null character.

The extra n is for the maximum length of the strings, so you never go in a forbidden location. In this particular case, you can use also strcmp because the second string is smaller then 32 and it will terminate first, but I think it's a good habit to use strncmp.